Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid
I have clone the repository below https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/main/source/nodejs but when I'm running npm install I'm getting the error below:
npm error code E401
npm error Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
has I understandard the registry is managed by microsoft but we need to provide a valid account, how can I be registered? Does I have to create an account?
Thanks in advance
